# Intento cambiar el innerText de un elemento, pero regresa al valor anterior de inmediato

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando cambiar el contenido de un `<li>` desde una función, pero no funciona, porque cambia automaticamente al valor anterior, esta es la lista:

```
<ul id="datalist">
    <li class="data" id="ciphr">.</li>
    <li class="data" id="secure">.</li>
</ul>
```

y esta es la función y algunas variables:

```
var cphrlabel = document.getElementById("ciphr");
var securitylabel = document.getElementById("secure");
var bcesar = document.getElementById("cesar");
var bvigenere = document.getElementById("vigenere");
var bsub = document.getElementById("sub");
var out = document.getElementById("outtext");
bcesar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeLabels("Caesar", "Low");
});
bvigenere.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeLabels("Vigenere", "Medium");
});
bsub.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeLabels("Substitution", "Low");
});

function changeLabels(name, slvl){
    window.cphrlabel.innerText = "Cipher: " + removeBannedChars(name);
    window.securitylabel.innerText = "Security: " + removeBannedChars(slvl);
}
```

Está es la función `removeBannedChars`, un usuario me pidio que pusiera el codigo:

```
function removeBannedChars(text){
var unbannedtext = "";
for(var char = 0; char < text.length; char++){
    if(text[char] == ">" || text[char] == "<"){
        continue;
    }
    unbannedtext += text[char];
}
return unbannedtext;
}
```

Hice algunos experimentos, como añadir un `console.log` a uno de los `eventListener` de los botones, cuando le doy click, aparece por un segundo y se despues se borra, por lo que creo que la página se refresca cada que se preciona ese botón.

Este es el HTML de los botones:

```
    <header>
    <h1 id="mainTitle">CipherMate</h1>
    <nav>
        <form id="buttons">
            <button class="navbut" id="cesar">caesar</button>
            <button class="navbut" id="vigenere">vigenere</button>
            <button class="navbut" id="sub">substitution</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Si ocupan más información sobre el codigo o lo que sea dejenlo en los comentarios, gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de la función `removeBannedChars`?

Comment: @Kiko_L Ya está.

Comment: Me parece que cuando precionas los botones se hace un refresh en la página, no tengo idea de por qué

Comment: Por favor agregá el HTML de los botones y todo lo que sea relevante.

Comment: @azeós Lo acabo de poner, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que agregarle a tus botones un `type="button"`. Al no hacerlo se les está aplicando el valor por defecto que es `submit`. Lo que genera que cada vez que los clickees se envíe el formulario. Como el formulario no tiene especificado ningún `action`, se está enviando al valor por defecto que es la URL desde donde lo estás enviando. Lo que genera la "sensación" de que se está actualizando la web.

```
<form id="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="navbut" id="cesar">caesar</button>
    <button type="button" class="navbut" id="vigenere">vigenere</button>
    <button type="button" class="navbut" id="sub">substitution</button>
</form>
```